# Jquery jtable in php not showing at front end table record

Tags: php

Using jquery jtable but not showing record list...at front end this showing data is not available while there are 10 records in the database.

```
    <link href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Scripts/jtable/themes/lightcolor/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //Prepare jTable
            jQuery('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 2,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=list',
                    createAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=update',
                    deleteAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    id: {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: false
                    },
                    name: {
                        title: 'Author Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    age: {
                        title: 'Age',
                        width: '20%'
                    },
                    RecordDate: {
                        title: 'Record date',
                        width: '30%',
                        type: 'date',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false
                    }
                }
            });

            //Load person list from server
            jQuery('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

        });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="PeopleTableContainer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yo should show your PersonActions.php file here.

Answer (score 0):

you must check the other page "PersonActions.php".

first you have to enter the table fields currectly in the position 
if the fields are like (id,name,age,date)
you have to enter like this

```
fields: {
    id: {
        key: true,
        create: false,
        edit: false,
        list: false
    },
    name: {
        title: 'Author Name',
        width: '40%'
    },
    age: {
        title: 'Age',
        width: '20%'
    },
    date: {
        title: 'Record date',
        width: '30%',
        type: 'date',
        create: false,
        edit: false
    }
}
```

and in "PersonActions.php" you have to check the connection,query and every thing